# getter function name 'doEmptyItemsExist'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am a Japanese web developer.

I am not good at English , but I want to be better.

I am making a task application, and I made a function like this in order to check if there are empty entry.

```
private get doEmptyItemsExist(): boolean {
    return this.title === '' || this.detail === '' || this.deadLine === ''
}
```

I use this for validate.

'doEmptyItemsExist'

Is this proper English?

And is this proper name for this function?

Is it better to say just 'emptyItemsExist'?

I thought if it starts with 'do', it can tells you that it returns boolean simply.

And I want to know 'emptyItemsExist' or 'emptyItemExists' which is better.

And I want to know proper word for 'item', like I thought maybe it's better to say 'entry'.

Someone, please help me.

Comment: this maybe off-topic for stackoverflow since this is language question...  (besides coding style. but also I'm not sure coding style is on topic)

Comment: an personally I won't start with verb in getter, it just weird to me.

Comment: should name as isNullOrEmpty

Comment: Thank you so much! So, is 'emptyItemsExist' better?

Comment: @HienNguyen I'm somewhat sure it's not the case.

Comment: I think the same as user 'apple apple'. Anycase, I thing your code on english is wellwritten :) . I would say 'entry' maybe for parameters and item for more generic concepts, usually in arrays or lists.

Comment: I would use `emptyItemExist`, but it's just my style.

Comment: apple apple , you said it's off topic, but you are kind, thank you. I won't use 'do' then.

Comment: Jesús Narváez Tamés, you are write. I see word 'item' often for item in array.

Comment: Hien Nguyen thank you. I see, but if you say 'is', it is write when entry is only one. I want to check if empty entry exist in all entries.

Comment: This is really more a naming convention question which is kind of opinion-based.  However, your question is very similar to this one: [Boolean method naming readability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1566745/691711).

Comment: A bit more concise: `isEmpty()`.

Comment: zero298 thank you. Oh, I see. So in this case, it is better not to start with 'do'.

Comment: Wex thank you. I see, but it is like checking only one entry. I want to check if empty entry exist in all entries.

Comment: What about `hasEmptyItem`?

Comment: ttulka thank you. Thant is a good name. But this class has more information not only about form. There are function like deleteTask too.

Comment: @akao although depends on the real use case , I guess maybe `valid` is a good name.

Comment: apple apple thank you. Then, how about 'areEntriesValid' or 'areAllEntriesValid'?